# Passing the index of the file (or the file) to a custom function in the previewContainer

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

**What I am trying to accomplish**

As users upload images, I would like to have it possible to change the order of the files after they have been added. As such, I have added two buttons inside the `previewTemplate` to move them up or down the array

```
...<div class="dz-success-mark"><span>✔</span></div><div class="dz-error-mark"><span>✘</span></div>
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
    <div ng-click="moveFileUp()">up</div><div ng-click="moveFileDown()">down</div>
</div>...
```

The two functions (`moveFileUp` and `moveFileDown`) both get called and have access to dropzone's self-generated array of files (`myDropZone.files`).

**My problem**

Both functions have no way of know what the index of the file or the file itself is. Is there anyway to pass either it to my custom functions. So that I can know which file to move?

**SideNote**

As you can maybe tell, I've wrapped dropzone inside an angular directive, I can post more of my code if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Your best bet is to pass the files to a separate array and deal with them there. In the `addedFile` event, pass  the file object to an other array and develop your own preview container with that array.